# Why should I remove script tags from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

I just discovered a framework removing the script tags from the markup after the page was finished loading.  I've tried searching for a "why", but all I discover is many people searching for a way to do it without saying why.

Is this a safety precaution?

Are there other tags that should be removed after as well?

---

As an example, here's a previous question that I asked about it just a little while ago:

[Why are <script> tags not showing up in the inspector in Firefox on the todomvc example for AngularJS but are for the source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056753/why-are-script-tags-not-showing-up-in-the-inspector-in-firefox-on-the-todomvc/21056907?noredirect=1#21056907)

That's originally where I discovered this.

I got one comment there that explained why he would do it *in his case.*

> I don't know angularjs that well to tell why they remove the script that are not templates, could be a coding guideline. I myself remove them, because jquery once had an unexpected behavior that had the result that scripts where executed each time one of their ancestors where wraped. The bug is fixed but to avoid that this happens again I remove them.

Comment: Because if it's a comment, for instance, then people can inject `script` tags into the page to perform additional behaviour that your page wasn't intended to perform. For PHP you can use http://uk3.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: *After* the DOM is done loading [on the client]? The only reason I can think of for that is to change the display/content - or to try and "hide" something. Removing a `<script [of type javascript]>` element is largely useless, because *the contents have already been evaluated* when it is added to the DOM. Any side-effects of the script (including adding global properties/functions) has already occurred and removing the `<script>` element won't "undo" such action.

Comment: @Wildhoney, but by that point wouldn't it be too late after the engine has consumed it?

Comment: One case where script elements *are* commonly removed (after being added) dynamically is when they are specifically used *to* inject data - JSONP is one example, as well as "AJAX-HTML updates" that allow <script> element processing.

Comment: I suppose it depends how the `script` tags are being removed. If it's an AJAX call and the tags are being stripped before being appended to the DOM then that makes sense, otherwise it's fruitless and can only serve the purpose of being pretty.

Comment: This is definitely something you don't want to do, as JSONP has a very evil tendency to introduce loopholes for people to introduce malicious code. Most major sites will test for JSONP and deny access, simply because I could inject whatever script I wanted into your source. Beyond that, JSONP has a very limited scope, as in you have to call it for every function you run. Just keep your `script` tags :-)

Comment: One of ExtJS features is to get data through `script` tag proxy, to avoid different domains problem. After data is accepted the `script` tags are removed (just because not to collect them too many in the DOM).